# Prevent 'AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally' Error at registration

Tags: ajax, users

I am getting the following error message when trying to register (using Drupal 7). Any idea on how to fix this?

This happens when trying to join here: http://test-caal.gotpantheon.com/

Thanks!

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
>   Debugging information follows.
>   Path: /modal_forms/ajax/register
>   StatusText: n/a
>   ResponseText: SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io ESMTP Postfix
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io ESMTP Postfix
>   "
>   SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io ESMTP Postfix
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io
>   250-PIPELINING
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-endpoint7ae8d1b7.chios.panth.io
>   250-PIPELINING
>   "
>   SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 10240000